# how to use JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator in intellij?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, viewpagerindicator

Hi there I am just newer in android development and I am trying to build my first app and I do will until now.

but I need to use **ViewPagerIndicator** so I do my search and I've found [JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) also I am using inellij IDE

but  the problem that when I want to add this library into my project I can't find the jar file and I don't know if the error from my side or what please any help.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a new module with the library sources and add it as a dependency to your main module. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/1369222) has detailed steps you can follow. Just replace the library used with ViewPagerIndicator.